# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: c#

Использую словарь для хранения данных пользователя. Запускается таймер, который проверяет, онлайн ли пользователь (как давно он присылал управляющий пакет, говорящий, что он онлайн).

Парой выскакивает ошибка

> Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key

Не могу понять с чем она связана.

Вот сам код:

```
private void TimerFunc(object stat)
{
    lock(this){
        for (int i = 0; i < userTable.table.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var ud = userTable.table.ElementAt(i);
                if(ud.Key == null || ud.Value == null)
                {
                     continue;//думал, что это как-то решит проблему
                }
                if (ud.Value.ip + ":" + ud.Value.port != serverData.IEPeP.ToString())//server не присылает нам пакет об онлайне, считается, что он онлайн всегда
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ud.Value.ip + ":" + ud.Value.port);
                    ud.Value.onlineTime -= 1000;//таймер запускает цикл каждую секунду
                    if (ud.Value.onlineTime <= 0)
                    {
                        if(nickTable.table.ContainsKey(ud.Value.nick))
                            nickTable.table.Remove(ud.Value.nick);
                        if(connectTable.table.ContainsKey(ud.Value.ip + ":" + ud.Value.port))
                            connectTable.table.Remove(ud.Value.ip + ":" + ud.Value.port);
                        if(userTable.table.ContainsKey(ud.Key))
                            userTable.table.Remove(ud.Key);
                        Debug.WriteLine("USER " + ud.Value.nick + " OFFLINE");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        userTable.table[ud.Key].onlineTime = ud.Value.onlineTime;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception obj)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("POINT 31+231: " + obj.Message);//вызывается это исключение
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так поставьте breakpoint в catch, и посмотрите, какой код кидает ошибку.

Comment: подозреваю, что `userTable` это `Dictionary` или другая коллекция, которая использует `KeyValuePair` в качестве элементов, в таком случае все правильно, `Key` в `KeyValuePair` не может быть `null` ни при каких условиях

Comment: Не хватает информации. Какой тип имеет userTable? На какой строке вылетает ошибка? Какой тип имеет ud?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ud.Value.nick != null && nickTable.table.ContainsKey(ud.Value.nick))
    nickTable.table.Remove(ud.Value.nick);
...
if(ud.Key != null && userTable.table.ContainsKey(ud.Key))
    userTable.table.Remove(ud.Key);
...
if(ud.Key != null)
    userTable.table[ud.Key].onlineTime = ud.Value.onlineTime;
```